# Prevent the line `load:... cmd:... running ...` upon SIGINFO

Tags: terminal, zsh, signals, terminal-emulator, iterm2

Issuing SIGINFO (e.g. by pressing ^T) while a terminal process is running usually results in a printout of a line

```
load: 2.93  cmd: sleep 7826 waiting 0.00u 0.00s
```

If I have written the tool that's running, I can make it catch the signal SIGINFO and react to it (e.g., by printout of certain information, like `dd` or `ping` are known to do). However, the above line is printed nevertheless. I wonder who is responsible for its being printed, and if it is possible to suppress it.

FYI: I'm using zsh inside iTerm2 on MacOS.

Comment: https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/stty suggests `stty -kerninfo` or `stty status ''`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Precisely what I was looking for, thanks. Feel free to post as an answer.